# Can i add my custom methods in the double quote builtin/extension in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So my plan is to add custom method to the quotes (str), I have seen adding methods to the str function in python, but its not that much of a help because of the heavy uses of quotes for strings.

I tried setting custom attribute to the quotes but i can't,

```
def method():

    print("quote method")

setattr("", "custom_method", method)
```

i get `TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'str'`

Answer (score 1):

You can't add custom methods to the built-in str type in Python, because the str type is immutable so it's attributes are fixed.

Instead of trying to add a custom method you could create a new class that represents a quote and define the custom method on this class.

e.g:

```
class Quote:
    def __init__(self, quote):
        self.quote = quote

    def custom_method(self):
        print("quote method")

# Create an instance of the Quote class
q = Quote("This is a quote.")

# Call the custom_method method on the instance
q.custom_method()
```